# Force Windows to check for printer status

Tags: windows, printer, network-printer, scanner

When I want to print something I have to turn on my network printer. This usually takes about a few seconds to get it online and then I can start printing from my phone or my MacBook.

However, with Windows, the printer's status stays "offline" for over 30min. I usually have to remove the printer and install it again to update the status to "online". The troubleshooter does show that the printer is offline and does some checks and shows the issue as resolved but the printer status stays offline. Hence Windows refuses to print anything.

Is there a way or command to force Windows to refresh the printer status?

This problem occurred on all of my Windows versions (>7).

Answer (score 0):

Check on what your printer is doing.

**(A)** If the printer is on your network (wired or wireless), give it a static IP on your network. The printer may be getting lost which is why reinstalling the printer (your post) works.

**(B)** If available, update the printer firmware

There is nothing special about Windows 7, 8, 10 or 11. Printing will turn the printer ON right away. Same for my iPhone.

**(C)** You might consider updating and reinstalling the Printer Driver.

Clear the Print Queue.

```
Click Start.
Type Command .
Right-click “Command Prompt” and select “Run as administrator“.

Type net stop spooler then press “Enter“.
Type del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers\* /Q then press “Enter“.
Type net start spooler then press “Enter“.
The print queue on your Windows should now be cleared.
```

Now download the current printer driver, install it, test it and do a final restart of the computer.

If you continue to have issues, you may wish to consider a different printer.