How to trigger the "Refresh" printer entry in Windows Explorer via CLI
I want to trigger the "Refresh"-entry in the shell:printersfolder in Windows Explorer using the CLI (CMD or Powershell). Is there a way?


Does the answer at https://superuser.com/questions/1725000/force-windows-to-check-for-printer-status help? Or https://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/forcing-a-refresh-of-network-printer-settings-from-print-server/

What problem does refreshing the printer solve for you? You can do Get-Printer | Format-List in powershell to see the current status, or Get-Printer | Get-PrintJob to see items in the print queue for example

@Cpt.Whale Sometimes users on a terminal server get the following error message when trying to print: "We couldn't print because there doens't seem to be a printer installed". What helps is doing the refresh, restart spooler or logoff/logon.

@DrMoishePippik restarting the spooler does help, but is not suitable, because it does affect all users working on that machine. Referring to your second link: I also don't want to delete the printer and add it again.

Based on @y-y answer, I was able to create the code that does what I had in mind.
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$printersFolder = $shell.Namespace(0x4)

#Refreshing a specific printer
$printersFolder.Items() | Where {$_.Name -eq "HP Pagewide"} |%{$_.InvokeVerb("Refresh")}

#Refreshing all printers
$printersFolder.Items() | %{$_.InvokeVerb("Refresh")}


Here is an example with PowerShell:
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$printersWindow = $shell.Windows() | Where LocationName -Like "*Printers*"
$printersWindow.Refresh()


This example helped me a lot! As far as I have seen, this code would only update the folder but not the individual printer. I was able to customize it based on that so that it does exactly what i wanted it to do. I have also modified it so that no GUI interaction is visible. I will post the code as a separate answer.
